# How to include file which in different folder in go templates

Tags: go-templates

For example there is `test.tpl` in folder `A`:

```
{{define "test"}} hello I am test {{end}}
```

another `index.tpl` in folder `B`:

`{{template "A/test"}} or {{template "test"}}`

Both do not work.

Comment: What is `inc`? Is it a folder in `A`?

Comment: my mistake, should be A

Comment: the problem still there,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`template.ParseFiles`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#ParseFiles) and to parse *all* templates. Use different names for each. This directory layout

```
.
├── A
│   └── index-A.tpl
├── B
│   └── index-B.tpl
└── main.go
```

With `A/index-A.tpl` containing

```
A
```

and `B/index-B.tpl` containing

```
B1
{{template "index-A.tpl"}}
B2
```

used by this code

```
package main

import (
        "os"
        "text/template"
)

func main() {
        t, err := template.ParseFiles("B/index-B.tpl", "A/index-A.tpl")
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
}
```

will produce this output:

```
B1
A    
B2
```

Note that *both* templates are named in `templateParseFiles` and that `B/index-B.tpl` references `index-a.tpl` by name *without the path*.

Comment: Is there any way to preserve the folder structure? I would like to be able to import files like `{{ tempalte "/A/index-A.tpl" }}`